# How to extract postimage url from wordpress post?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Hey guys. So my question is just like in the title. How to extract postimage url from wordpress post? So for example if wordpress `postimage()` function outputs something like:

```
<img src="some_img_url.jpg">
```

I'm only interested in some_img_url.jpg.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what that is? What is some example output?

Answer (score 0):

The question sounds quite vague like this (to me at least), but at first glance – and if it's a quick client side solution that you're looking for(?) – I'd try using jQuery, more specifically the *.attr()* method. See the last example of the official documentation, for example: http://api.jquery.com/attr/